# AbortController is not working in ajax and vue.js

Tags: ajax, vue.js, abortcontroller

I want to cancel the API when I leave the page, but it is not work in AbortController, here is my code snippet

```
import { fetchSingleList } from '@/api/scada'
data() {
  return {
    abortController: new AbortController()
  }
}
beforeDestroy() {
  this.abortController.abort()
},
methods: {
  getData(){
    fetchSingleList(data, { signal: this.abortController.signal }).then(res => ())
  }
}
```

here is the `fetchSingleList` function

```
export function fetchSingleList(data) {
  return request({
    url: 'api/scada/report',
    method: 'post',
    data
  });
}
```

and the `request` function is from axios interceptors

```
service.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    return config;
  },
  error => {
    // Do something with request error
    console.log(error); // for debug
    Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
service.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    return response.data;
  },
  error => {
    let message = error.message;
    if (error.response.data && error.response.data.errors) {
      message = error.response.data.errors;
    } else if (error.response.data && error.response.data.error) {
      message = error.response.data.error;
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

my axios version is `^0.22.0`

Comment: What is the request function, is it a custom function or you are using a library?

Comment: hi, the request function is axios interceptors, I'll paste it later

Answer (score 1):

In the `fetchSingleList`, you need to combine the `data` and `signal` in one object, as you have just one parameter.

```
  getData(){
    fetchSingleList({ data, signal: this.abortController.signal }).then(res => ())
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my data is in config.data, so I modify my code in axios interceptors, and it works!

here is the code

#### axios interceptors

```
service.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  let cfg = {...config}
    if (config.data && config.data.data) {
      cfg = {
        ...config,
        data: config.data.data,
        signal: config.data.signal
      }
    }
    console.log(cfg)
    return cfg;
})
```

#### api(vue SFC)

```
fetchSingleList({ data: data, signal: this.abortController.signal }).then(res => {})
```